# Make an item glow when the player is walking

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game (point & click) and I'm trying to make the usable item glow when the player is walking. It’s quite simple but I don’t why I fail. I must have missed something.

I have already the code as my usable item is glowing when I'm putting it on an other usable item. So I've got a `Engine` class where I'm trying to put the code that make the item glow when the player is walking. And a `DraggedItem` Class. This class allows the user to drag inventory items over the stage.

In my `DraggedItem` class I've got this function :

```
private function itemGlow(isGlowing:Boolean):void{
    if (isGlowing){
        var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
        glow.color = 0xFFFF00;
        glow.alpha = .75;
        glow.blurX = 10;
        glow.blurY = 10;
        glow.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM;

        draggedItem.filters = [glow];
    } else {
        draggedItem.filters = null;
    }
}
```

In my `Engine` class I'd like to use this function when my player is walking.

I tought I could put something like this :

```
back = new Background(stage, thisBack);
back.currentBack.ground.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shineItems, false, 0, true);

private function shineItems(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(shineItems);
    var thisClip = usableItems
    if (playerControl){
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("playerMoving"));
        draggedItem.itemGlow(true); 
    }
}
```

But it's not it.
I've must import the function in the wrong way.

So I've try to add in the `Engine` Class and change `draggedItem.itemGlow;` by `itemGlow;`.

```
private function itemGlow(isGlowing:Boolean):void{
    if (isGlowing){
        var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
        var thisClip = usableItems
        glow.color = 0xFFFF00;
        glow.alpha = .75;
        glow.blurX = 10;
        glow.blurY = 10;
        glow.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM;


        thisClip.filters = [glow];
    } else {
        thisClip.filters = null;
    }
}
```

But it's not working either.

Any idea ?

---

EDIT

I've put draggedItem.itemGlow(true); in the shineItems function and I've got this error now : 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::Engine/shineItems()[C:\Users\stephanberger4\Desktop\07 novembre\Tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\Engine.as:321]

line 321 is : draggedItem.itemGlow(true);

Comment: Ok, I've marked the function itemGlow as PUBLIC (it was private). But I've got an other error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::Engine/shineItems()[C:\Users\stephanberger4\Desktop\07 novembre\Tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\Engine.as:321] It seems that draggedItem.itemGlow(true); is the problem..

Comment: I think I have to define the value of draggedItem... So put draggedItem= something ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an instance of the DraggedItem class that you want to glow, you can set a DraggedItem instance's filters (from within the class) like this:

```
filters = [glow];
```

or:

```
this.filters = [glow];
```

This assumes DraggedItem extends DisplayObject, to access the filters property.
Also, in the shineItems function, you refer to itemGlow as a property when it is a function; it should be:

```
draggedItem.itemGlow(true);
```

or

```
draggedItem.itemGlow(false);
```

Comment: Thank you moosefetcher. I've put draggedItem.itemGlow(true); and now I've got this error : Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::Engine/shineItems()[C:\Users\stephanberger4\Desktop\07 novembre\Tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\Engine.as:321]

Comment: Do you ever create draggedItem as an instance of the DraggedItem class? ie: draggedItem = new DraggedItem();  This should most probably happen in the constructor function of your Engine class. You will also need to declare draggedItem as a variable of Engine, ie: private var draggedItem:DraggedItem; This should happen directly after the class declaration of Engine. You might also want to trace the various elements used on the problem line to establish which is 'null'.

Comment: I should also check that your itemGlow function IS now 'public', right? If it's 'private' it can't be accessed from outside the class.

Comment: I've declared draggedItem as a variable yes. But as an instance, I've got a problem. When I put draggedItem = new DraggedItem(); he wants me to put 2 arguments.. (seems fair as the function DraggedItem in the DraggedItem class is public function DraggedItem(stageRef:Stage, grabbedItem:Object) ). So what arguments do I have to put ? (if I put "Stage" and "Object" I've got an error)

Comment: Yes my itemGlow function is now 'public'

Comment: Check the constructor function of DraggedItem. The types of parameters it's asking for should be in brackets after the class name. Knowing which types of objects DraggedItem needs should remind you which objects to pass to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40747/discussion-between-user2421975-and-moosefetcher)